# Python sorted dict in formatting expression

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary

I have this formatting expression:

```
def __str__(self): 

        result = "\n".join({("{}: {}").format(key, self.__dict__[key]) for key, value in sorted(self.__dict__.items())}) 

        return result
```

The code runs but it is not sorted. I don't see why it is not being sorted. It returns the code below and every time it is in a different order.

```
currentPL: -438.627395715
portfolio: Balance: 10101
Transactions: 10
exitPrice: 1.14686
exitTime: 2017-07-12 06:0
entryTime: 2017-07-12 06:
currentlyOpen: True
entryPrice: 1.14686
direction: Long
currentPrice: 1.14188
transactionPL: 627.994644
currentPL100: -0.00434229
units: 88077.79030439684

portfolio: Balance: 10101
Transactions: 10
currentPrice: 1.14228
exitTime: 2017-07-12 06:0
entryTime: 2017-07-12 06:
currentlyOpen: True
entryPrice: 1.14686
direction: Long
transactionPL: 627.994644
currentPL100: -0.00399351
currentPL: -403.396279594
exitPrice: 1.14686
units: 88077.79030439684

...
```

Comment: Because the "list" in  your format expression is a set. Use `[...]` instead of `{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `'\n'.join` on a set (an unordered type) which defeats the initial purpose of ordering in the first place:

You could use a list (a sequence):

```
"\n".join([...])
```

Or remove those and use the generator expression directly. Here's a quite readable vesion that uses [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

result = "\n".join(starmap("{}: {}".format, sorted(self.__dict__.items()))
```